# Cant Upload File To Host with web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, asp.net-web-api2, image-uploading, dropzone.js

when i run site at local system file upload work fine 
but in virtual host (plesk)
**when i want upload file to site 
i got this error**
how i can fix this ?

> it is an error to use a section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.
>    This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being
>   configured as an application in IIS
>
> An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error
>   settings for this application prevent the details of the application
>   error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could,
>   however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

*api upload method **

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Files")]
    public JsonResult Files_Post([IoCModelBinder(typeof(NullableEntityModelBinder))] MediaCategory mediaCategory)
    {
        try
        {
            var list = new List<ViewDataUploadFilesResult>();
            foreach (string files in Request.Files)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[files];
                if (_fileService.IsValidFileType(file.FileName))
                {
                    ViewDataUploadFilesResult dbFile = _fileService.AddFile(file.InputStream, file.FileName,
                        file.ContentType, file.ContentLength,
                        mediaCategory);
                    list.Add(dbFile);
                }
            }
            return Json(list.ToArray(), "text/html", Encoding.UTF8);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

in console:

```
File
accepted
:
true
height
:
473
lastModified
:
1478297024176
lastModifiedDate
:
Sat Nov 05 2016 01:33:44 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)
name
:
"nvs5.jpg"
previewElement
:
div.dz-preview.dz-processing.dz-image-preview.dz-error.dz-complete
previewTemplate
:
div.dz-preview.dz-processing.dz-image-preview.dz-error.dz-complete
processing
:
true
size
:
100824
status
:
"error"
type
:
"image/jpeg"
upload
:
Object
bytesSent
:
101006
progress
:
100
total
:
101006
__proto__
:
Object
webkitRelativePath
:
""
width
:
840
xhr
:
XMLHttpRequest
__proto__
:
File
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Find My Answer 
Problem caused by WebApi Method name ,
After I Renamed That Problem Solved ;
(Name convention in WebApi )